How to update the rules of multiple RTDB instances using the firebase tools?
I would like to run firebase deploy --only database and it deploys the Firebase Real time database rules for each of my databases instances.
I would like the config of firebase.json / .firebaserc and wherever that applies if that's possible.

The documentation suggests that you can identify a single database instance on the command line (it says nothing about multiple instances).  If you need more than than what's been documented, then you should file a feature request on GitHub - we can't help you with that.

thanks for the reply, i have asked chat GPT and it gave me some config for firebase.json to reference multiple databases. But i wanted an official / trustable source to confirm this or refute it. So the answer is that i can't do that because it's not supported, alright i will update them manually or via the REST API

It seems it was in the documentation that i had not found previously :

So i simply have to replace my-db-1 for example by my database name (the part of the URL that i pick when i create my database) and create my custom rules.json files, then apply the config as a List in firebase.json as shown in the above screen.

A single run of firebase deploy will only update a single Realtime Database instance. If you want to update multiple instances, you will have to run firebase deploy for each of them, and identify the correct database instance each time.

Thanks for the reply i note the solution.
I have seen this link in the meantime : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding#edit_and_deploy_for_each_instance
Since you didn't mention this in your answer, is it actually answering my need ? I will try it tomorrow that's why i am asking now because i can't test it

Oh wow, yes that does allow for updating multiple databases with one call after all! I'll delete my (wrong) answer, and you should probably post your own.
